# Testing if property exists

Tags: php

I read on [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php#97538) that `isset()` is faster than `property_exists()` and we should use a combination of both like

```
if (isset($this->fld) || property_exists($this, 'fld')) {
```

But why can't I just use isset then?

```
if (isset($this->fld)) {
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Because `property_exists` will tell you if its even a defined property of the class/object where as isset doesnt make that distinction. for example:

```
class A {
  protected $hello;
}

class B {

}
```

using `property_exists($this, 'hello')` in **class A** will return `true`, while using it in **class B** will return `false`. `isset` will return `false` in *both* instances.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how your program is done, but if you read the comments in the manual it will help with explaining idiosyncrasies of a function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

The important part is here:

> The documentation leaves out the
>   important case of new properties you
>   add to objects at run time.  In fact,
>   property_exists will return true if
>   you ask it about such properties.

Comment: i also prefer isset for testing if a property is not empty