# Prevent undefined variable error when checking for empty variable

Tags: php

I have the below function which checks if there are any values in two variables and then adds them up, or tells you if there aren't any. It actually works totally fine, BUT it also returns warnings for undefined variables when I leave them empty. Can anyone explain why this is? and how I can correct it?

I have searched but perhaps because of my lack of general knowledge on the subject I couldn't search efficiently.

```
function add_up($first, $second){
  if($first == "" and $second == ""){
    return 'No numbers';}
  else {
    return $first + $second;
  }
}
echo add_up();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct PHP code to check if a variable exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852094/correct-php-code-to-check-if-a-variable-exists)

Comment: If you mean that if just leave it empty and call the function without any arguments, then it is simply because you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Rizier123 It may just be for the sake of an example. As doing this is useful when you are checking for POST data.

Comment: How you calling the function when you getting error?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam They are just getting warning messages, the call is at the end of the code block: `add_up()`.

Comment: Look mihai stancu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to specify a function argument as optional you must define a default value for it:

```
function add_up($first = '', $second = ''){
  if($first == "" and $second == ""){
    return 'No numbers';}
  else {
    return $first + $second;
  }
}
echo add_up();
```

The warning represents the fact that both arguments are required (since they have no default values defined) meaning the function must be called with both arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for something like this:

```
function add_up($first, $second){
  if(!isset($first, $second)){
    return 'No numbers bitch';}
  else {
    return $first + $second;
  }
}
echo add_up();
```

Comment: @RyanVincent you are correct but what I measured here was that the user may send some unset values or calling add_up(null, null) still it will give error. with my solution you can skip that at least. but you are right about the default values too